# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in field.info.inc

Tags: 7, entities

I'm cloning my client's drupal 7.15 site from online to my localhost. I received a copy of site folder and a copy of a sql dump file. I installed them into my localhost.

When I run the site, firstly I encountered the error:

> Fetal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\includes\common.inc on line 7679

But the error went away when I did clear all cache tables manually via phpMyAdmin.
Unfortunately, the next error appeared.

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\modules\field\field.info.inc on line 294

**[Edit]**
I installed Drush and navigated to my site in Drush command line, but I could not run commands except "drush" because of that error.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite>drush user-login
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.       [error]
>
> Error: Unsupported operand types in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\modules\field\field.info.inc, line 294
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite>drush status
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.       [error]
>
> Error: Unsupported operand types in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\modules\field\field.info.inc, line 294
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite>drush cache-clear
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.       [error]
>
> Error: Unsupported operand types in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\modules\field\field.info.inc, line 294

When I traced into **field.info.inc**, I found that `$instance['settings']` ( of the first parameter of [_field_info_prepare_instance](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/_field_info_prepare_instance/7) ) is missing for the field `field_tags`. Thus, the "+=" operation for arrays failed.

```
print $instance
Array
(
    [id] => 5
    [field_id] => 3
    [field_name] => field_tags
    [entity_type] => node
    [bundle] => article
    [deleted] => 0
)
print $instance["settings"]

****************
print field_info_instance_settings() call on taxonomy_term_reference
Array
(
    [user_register_form] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems indicate that the copy did not come out right. Rather than try to diagnose the symptom, start over and copy the site again from scratch. If you can use Drush, perhaps [Drush rebuild](http://drupal.org/project/rebuild) would help.  You could also use the drush rsync and drush sql-sync commands directly.

Comment: I'm intalling my client site copy to my localhost. I have no access to my client server.

Comment: Please check my revised question. Any idea?

Comment: I would not try to diagnose the symptoms with the corrupt site, but would instead focus on the process you used to clone the site, and correct that until the copy works as well as the original.

Comment: Thanks. Just seeking any advice from drupal masters. Not intend you to diagnose it. I got to know that Drush would not help to diagnose the symptoms.

Comment: All that you are going to discover vis-a-vis your missing $instance['settings'] is that your copy of your Drupal site is corrupt, because it is missing something critical. Once you discover this, your resolution will be to go back and copy the site again, insuring that all needed parts of the database are present, and all needed files -- and the right version of all of the needed files -- are present.  You could save yourself a lot of time if you skip straight to re-copying your site.

Comment: Note also that your Drush failures above are bootstrapping your corrupt Drupal site, which is why they are failing. You should still be able to use drush rsync to re-copy your files, because it does not bootstrap Drupal.  sql-sync does a partial bootstrap of the destination site to look up your database settings. This will probably work if your files have been copied over correctly, but if you are having trouble with sql-sync, you can make drush skip the callback step by copying your db info from settings.php into your site alias record.

Comment: I just received a copy of the site folder and a copy of a sql dump file from my client. I have no access to their server. Thus, I cannot do rsync or sql-sync. I already stated this in my first comment. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Finally, I got db access from my client. I downloaded the sql dump for each module by module and imported them into my localhost. It was ok for me. I got the site run in my localhost, except some minor warnings.