# How to configure Drush on Windows 7?

Tags: 7, drush

I'm working on drupal in Windows environment. Most drupal developers recommend to use [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush). I know it is a very useful command line tool for drupal development.

I downloaded [the Drush installer for Windows](https://github.com/drushonwindows/Drush-on-Windows-Installer) and have installed it, but I don't know how to use it and how it works together with drupal.

**[Edit]**
The main problem is that when I launched the drush command line windows and then I was stuck with what I should do next. I'm looking for how can I connect to my local site ( D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite ) via drush and I just want to play around the site.

My site stopped working and got the error from [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44605/fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types-in-field-info-inc). I was googling for the error, but no luck.
I think Drush could help me for this.

What is a good start point to study Drush?

**[Edit]**
Most documentation describe Drush on linux. I'm not familiar with linux, ssh, PowerShell, minsw, msysgit, cygwin etc.

- I checked the [FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20140912220827/http://drush.ws/faq) and [Resources](http://web.archive.org/web/20140912220827/http://drush.ws/resources) on the site [drush.ws](http://web.archive.org/web/20140912220827/http://drush.ws/) Some of videos and screencasts are listed for older versions.
- I also found [this](http://drupal.org/node/594744), but I'm not sure **Step by Step** is needed when I used **Executable Installer**. Will the installer make me configured everything for ready-to-use?
- The installation guide [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140912220827/http://drush.ws/drush_windows_installer) is too general. I'm not sure I need [MsysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/).
- [This](http://drupal.org/node/594744) and [that](http://drupal.org/node/330023) mention about **Gnuwin32**. I chose it to install during setup.

Thus, I'm just looking for a short-to-the-point reference or tutorial to configure Drush on Windows 7 and connect to my site.

Comment: To down-voted guys: This question does not show research effort or is not useful? If not, I will delete this.

Comment: I'm not sure why they downvoted but I upvote since this question is useful for other people using this kind of environment. They should explain why they downvoted the question to explain their action.

Comment: in drush command line do you get results for the `drush` command? If yes, you have successfully configured drush for windows :) If not check for the installation guide in the link again.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but "What is a good start point to study Drush?" is a too generic question. If you add more details about what you are trying to achieve, that would make the question more helpful. The [Help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) says, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." It also says, "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: @ninjascorner Absolutely no pressure should be put on people to leave comments when they downvote. Voting is anonymous and that's how it should remain.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the question showed lack of initiative, and was difficult to answer. Your edit helped only a little. Lack of initiative: You found and installed Drush for Windows, but it was unclear if you looked at the "FAQ" or "Resources" tab on the same site, or read the README that came with Drush. All of these sources give a lot of information on how to get started with Drush. Hard to answer: Drush on Windows works with Powershell, DOS, Cygwin and Mingw / Msysgit. It is unclear from your question whether you know anything about any of these shells.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was very helpful and highlighted to me rather than down-voting without any comment. I'm not familiar with shells. I'm just looking for a very good start point, not details from bottom to top. ninjascorner also helped me.

Comment: @Clive: Yes, voting is (should be) anonymous. Down-voting without any comment/reason and without inquiry will not help to others. Thus, stackexhange should add pressure on downvote so that anyone can see/review it on one's profile and revise the question. The answers I got here are very helpful to me and they will also help others who may encounter a situation like me.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Thank your for your point. I use this community to help each other and share experience as answer. I think down-voting if deviate from the faq is useless.

Comment: @SithuKyaw I'm afraid that's just not how it works on StackExchange sites. If you go to meta.stackoverflow.com and search for this issue you'll find literally dozens of requests to force people to leave comments when downvoting. All of them are heavily, heavily downvoted. The community is fiercely protective of it's right to downvote anonymously, and personally I agree with that. Oh, I didn't downvote this by the way :)

Comment: Voting is the way users in a Stack Exchange site push up good questions, and pull down bad questions. For this reason, there aren't useless votes, as any of them help separate the good questions from the bad questions. Also, it is not required that who down-voted explains what is wrong with a question, as everybody is possibly able to do that.

Comment: Mine is not a bad question :) I admitted it was too generic and unclear. At least, my question is getting nearer to the right track because of your comments and answers. Thanks to all!

Comment: Bash intro: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2784 Bash reference manual: http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_toc.html Bash man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: are you sure PATHs are correctly configured? for example what you see when you enter `php -v` in your command line?