# Problems installing drush 7.0 on Windows

Tags: drush

I've been using drush 6 quite happily on a Windows machine (where I'm testing Drupal 7 sites) for some time, installed if I remember rightly using an MSI installer, under "Program Files". I'm working behind a proxy so had to alter the `drush/gunwin32/etc/wgetrc` file in order to enter the proxy settings.

Since downloading the service_container module drush 6 no longer works on that site, it keeps giving me **"Can't inherit abstract function"** errors. So I thought I would try upgrading to drush 7.0

But how to do this? I downloaded the zip file and can successfully execute drush commands from the Windows command line. However there appears to be no msi installer (so there is no "drush" command, you must run **drush.bat**), nor can I see a **drush.sh** command (for example) to run drush under Git Bash shell, and above all I cannot find anywhere to configure my proxy settings - so I'm a bit stuck!

Comment: Try: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PHP-at-Scale-on-the-Microsoft-Platform/10-Managing-Drupal-on-Windows-with-Drush

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Drush on Windows 7?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44686/how-to-configure-drush-on-windows-7)